# What is actually num_unit in LSTM cell circuit?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I tried very hard to search everywhere, but I couldn't find what `num_units` in TensorFlow actually is. I tried to relate my question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901047/what-is-num-units-in-tensorflow-basiclstmcell), but I couldn't get clear explanation there.

---

In TensorFlow, when creating an LSTM-based RNN, we use the following command

```
cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=5, state_is_tuple=True)
```

As [Colah's blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) says, this is a basic LSTM cell:

[image]

Now, suppose my data is:

```
idx2char = ['h', 'i', 'e', 'l', 'o']

# Teach hello: hihell -> ihello
x_data = [[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3]]   # hihell
x_one_hot = [[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # h 0
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],   # i 1
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # h 0
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],   # e 2
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],   # l 3
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]]  # l 3

y_data = [[1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 4]]    # ihello
```

My input is:

```
x_one_hot = [[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # h 0
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],   # i 1
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],   # h 0
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],   # e 2
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],   # l 3
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]]  # l 3
```

which is of shape `[6,5]`.

In [this blog](https://jasdeep06.github.io/posts/Understanding-LSTM-in-Tensorflow-MNIST/), we have the following picture

[image]

As far as I know, the `BasicLSTMCell` will unroll for `t` time steps, where `t` is my number of rows (please, correct me if I am wrong!). For example, in the following figure, the LSTM is unrolled for `t = 28` time steps.

[image]

In the Colah's blog, it's written

> each line carries an entire vector

So, let's see how my `[6,5]` input matrix will go through this LSTM-based RNN.

[image]

*If my above diagram is correct, then what exactly is `num_units` (which we defined in LSTM cell)*? Is it a parameter of an LSTM cell?

If `num_unit` is a parameter of a single LSTM cell, then it should be something like:

[image]

[image]

*If above diagram is correct, then where are those 5 `num_units` in the following schematic representation of the LSTM cell (according to Colah's blog)?*

[image]

---

If you can give your answer with a figure, that would be really helpful! You can edit or create new whiteboard diagram [here](https://awwapp.com/b/schvorrmy?dis=%5B%5B%22edit-board-name%22%5D%2C%5B%22no-init-modal%22%5D%5D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is quite correct. However, unfortunately, there is inconsistency between the Tensorflow terminology and the literature. In order to understand, you need to dig through the Tensorflow implementation code.

A **cell** in the Tensorflow universe is called an LSTM layer in Colah's universe (i.e an unrolled version). That is why you always define a single cell, and not a layer in your Tensorflow architecture. For example,

```
cell=rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=5,state_is_tuple=True)
```

Check the code here.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef96faaf02be54b7eb5945244c881126a4d38761/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L90

> The definition of cell in this package differs from the definition used in the literature. In the literature, cell refers to an object with a single scalar output. The definition in this package refers to a horizontal array of such units.

Therefore, in order to understand num_units in Tensorflow, its best to imagine an unrolled LSTM as below.

[image]

In an unrolled version, you have an input **X_t** which is a tensor. When you specify an input of the shape

> [batch_size,time_steps,n_input]

to Tensorflow, it knows how many times to unroll it from your **time_steps** parameter.

So if you have **X_t** as a 1D array in TensorFlow, then in the Colahs unrolled version each LSTM cell **x_t** becomes a scalar value (Please observe the capital case X (vector/array) and small case x(scalar) - Also in Colah's figures)

If you have **X_t** as a 2D array in the Tensorflow, then in the Colahs unrolled version each LSTM cell **x_t** becomes a 1D array/vector (as in your case here) and so on.

Now here comes the most important question.

**How would Tensorflow know what is the output/hidden dimension ** Z_t/H_t** ?

(Please note the difference between H_t and Z_t - I usually prefer to keep them separate as H_t goes back to input (the loop) and **Z_t** is the output - Not shown in figure)

Would it be same dimension as **X_t** ?

**No**.It can be of any different shape. You need to specify it to the Tensorflow. And that is **num_units - The Output Size**

Check here in the code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef96faaf02be54b7eb5945244c881126a4d38761/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L298-L300

```
    @property
    def output_size(self):
        return self._num_units
```

Tensorflow uses the implementation of LSTM cell as defined in Colahs universe from the following paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2329.pdf