# LSTM/RNN weight sharing/communication among units (parameter) in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Is there any sort of communication/sharing happening between units inside a RNN/LSTM layer ?

The below figure is cropped from accepted answer [How to interpret clearly the meaning of the units parameter in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932767/how-to-interpret-clearly-the-meaning-of-the-units-parameter-in-keras)
Here the author connects various units in the RNN/LSTM layer (marked in red).

I am aware that, in RNN/LSTM parameter sharing happens across timesteps, but does it happen between units?

EX code

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_dim=3))
model.summary()
```

[image]

I came across this lecture where professor makes it very clear that,  there is no communication/sharing/something else between  (units in Keras RNN/LSTM) in the same layer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nnSjZBJVDs&list=PLQflnv_s49v_i1OVqE0DENBk-QJt9THjE&index=10&t=396s

I think The communication/sharing doesnt happen between cells in the same layer.  Can someone please clarify/think otherwise ?

Answer (score 1):

> I think The communication/sharing doesnt happen between cells in the same layer. Can someone please clarify/think otherwise ?

There are no communication between units in a standard LSTM layer (at least in every standard implementation I know of). The same way you don't have any connection between unit in a Dense layer.

I'm not saying this is not feasible or bad, but this sure does not describe a standard RNN/LSTM unit.